# How do I Sign an Application Use Click-Once to Satisfy AppLocker?

Tags: clickonce, code-signing-certificate

AppLocker will not recognize my application as signed, and I am using ClickOnce deployment.

- I selected the option "Sign the Assembly" on the Signing tab
- As well as 'Sign the ClickOnce manifests'
- I have a valid certificate, not a test certificate
- I also used the option "Use application manifest for trust information"
- I also used the option "Enable ClickOnce security settings'

Using the PowerShell command 'Get-ApplockerFileInformation', I verified that

- "Setup.exe" is signed and the pulisher is reported
- But my *application's exe does not have a publisher!*

(That is, I navigated to the location in AppData\local... where my exe is installed and ran the PowerShell command on it there)

I have tried running SN.exe to generate a strong name, no help.

The upshot is AppLocker prevents my application from launching because it cannot verify the publisher, even though my Setup.Exe file has a publisher. Is there anything I can do with click-once to sign the exe that is installed on users PCs?

Answer (score 0):

you should sign the APP.EXE separately from the SETUP.EXE - i do it in Post-Build script. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18636102/1246870) for more details.