# ClickOnce application signed with purchased CA shows "Unknown Publisher"

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I know this question has been asked a lot. I already tried many of the solutions in other questions, but is not working.
The application target framework is 4.5.2.
I'm working on Windows 7 with Visual Studio Community 2017.

The certificate is a code signing certificate from Sectigo. Standard version (not EV).

[image: Certificate general]
[image: Certificate purpose]
[image: Certificate path]

I'm using the Signing tab on Project properties to sign the application.

[image: Visual Studio Signing tab]

I'm publishing to a folder in my machine after that I upload the published files to a web server.
When I check the properties of the setup.exe and myApp.exe both are signed and timestamped correctly or at least it seems so.

[image: Digital signatures]

Also, the *myApp.application* file in `\path\publish_folder\`, the `\path\publish_folder\Application Files\myApp_1_0_0_0\myApp.application` file and the `\path\publish_folder\Application Files\myApp_1_0_0_0\myApp.exe.manifest` have the `<publisherIdentity>` tag that matches with the certificate.

Everything seems good, even when I download the application and run the setup.exe I get the following warning, which is ok:
[image: setup.exe warning]

When setup.exe is executed is published is presented right but after the `setup.exe` calls *myApp.application* then it shows this warning with "**Unknown Publisher**" and that is the problem:
[image: myApp.application warning]

I tried installing the certificate in the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" store, as well as in the "Trusted Publishers" store and in the "Personal" store, and publish the application again but the same thing happens.

In other questions said that the visual studio signing tab only sign the manifest but no the executable, as you can see this is not my case (setup.exe and myApp.exe have the digital signatures correctly) but even though I decided to try signing using *signtool sign* command (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\signtool.exe) and build/publish events as theses answers proposed without luck:

- [.NET ClickOnce Signing results in "Unknown Publisher"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132305/net-clickonce-signing-results-in-unknown-publisher)
- https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/windows-8-and-clickonce-the-definitive-answer-2/

I think the only thing I'm missing to try is the "sign assembly" option (checkbox in Signing tab in Visual Studio), but when I do it the first time I get the error:

```
Cannot import the following key file: myKey.pfx. The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or manually install the certificate to the Strong Name CSP with the following key container name: VS_KEY_5578EF228F7A794C myApp
```

Then the second time I try I get this error:

```
Error importing key: An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

I signed the application and made the publish using Visual Studio Professional 2019 and it worked. Now it still shows the warning but with the publisher correctly in both warnings.

Comment: Hi, I'm getting the exact same issue (Unknow Publisher when running setup.exe, but OK publisher when launching the application). I sign the application from VS 2019 community. Any idea if I actually need the professional version for this to work?

Comment: Juan: I can verify it does work in Community.  However, if you're using Comodo's certificates, [don't use their timestamp server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66879678/).

Comment: @user2006616 Wow thank you that worked! I would've never figured this out