# click once application shows unknown publisher after add self signing

Tags: clickonce

click once application signing certificate not working. 
I have added my self signing certificate(using makeCert.cex) in signing tab.
but my click once application shows unknown publisher while running the set up.

please help me out from this problem

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Signing tab - but it only signs setup.exe - and not the actual application.exe file. This way you don't get a "warning" prompt when you install the app, but you get it when you run it. You need to sign application.exe separately - and there is no UI for that in Visual Studio, you need to use PostBuild task: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18636102/1246870

Comment: i have tred but it shows error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. There are multiple root elements. Line 19, position 3.

Comment: error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\signtool.exe" sign /f "C:\Users\WASS\Desktop\Projects\UAS\USAFormsWPFAppVB\UAS.pfx" /p uas /v "C:\Users\WASS\Desktop\Projects\UAS\USAFormsWPFAppVB\obj\Debug\UASForms.exe"" exited with code 3.

Comment: also i have find reason for above error and fix the error

Comment: but the command running for ever build even though it is shows the unknown publisher